# sufficient condition for discrete valuation ring

Tags: proof-verification, local-field

In Section 2 of 'Local Fields : Jean-Pierre Serre', the author proves the following proposition (Propositions are numbered following the book) :

$\textbf{Proposition 3:}$ Let $A$ be a Noetherian integral domain. In order that $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, it is neccessary and sufficient that it satisfy the two following conditions:

(i)$A$ is integrally closed.

(ii) $A$ has a unique non-zero prime ideal.

The author takes about a page to prove the sufficient condition of the proposition, while it seems to me that it is immediate from the proposition just above this proposition, which I mention below :

$\textbf{Proposition:}$  Let $A$ be a commutative ring. In order that $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, it is neccessary and sufficient that it be a Noetherian local ring, and that its maximal ideal be generated by a non-nilpotent element.

Now, if $A$ satisfies (ii) of $\text{Proposition 3:}$, then it is commutative (being an integral domain), Noetherian by assumption, local (since unique non-zero prime ideal $\implies$ unique maximal ideal) and the maximal ideal is obviously generated by a non-nilpotent element, since only nilpotent element in an integral domain is $0$.

Comment: Is it clear that $\mathfrak p$ is principal?

Comment: is it required? Proposition 2 only requires that it be Noetherian, local and maximal ideal should be generated by non-nilpotent element.

Comment: @iser1430 so it does require $\mathfrak m=(a)$ (where additionally $a^n\ne 0$ for all $n$)

Comment: oh sorry, can you please close this question? I don't have the privilege.